# ruby gsub not working as expected

Tags: ruby

I am passing in a symbol -  :table_single

I want to remove "_single":

```
short_name = column_name[0].to_s
    short_column_attribute = short_name.gsub(/"_single"/, "")
```

But it is still coming in as "table_single"?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a superfluous double quotes inside your regular expression:

```
#                ⇓       ⇓
short_name.gsub(/"_single"/, "")
```

The correct version is:

```
short_name.gsub(/_single/, "")
```

Or, in case there is simple string removal, regexp itself is superfluous:

```
short_name.gsub('_single', "")
```

Comment: excellent answer but I am much more interested in how you inserted those down arrows as this seems like it would be extremely useful in the future

Comment: @engineersmnky I use my own keyboard mapping. Whether you are on Linux, it’s quite easy. MacOS/Win suck as usual.

Comment: Microsoft has a free program called the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, which is actually quite good and easy to use.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah, they did it finally? It sounds like past another decade we could expect them to ship with Windows 25 a ready-to-use console out of the box.

Comment: It was released over a decade ago, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex, just write

```
short_name.gsub('_single', '')
```